# There is limitation in the use of Windows Azure Mobile with Android service that start at boot?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I wrote an Android application that communicates with Windows Azure Mobile Services typically sends data between the device and the android Azure database, but when I inserted the same code a service that starts automatically on boot does not run.
I have no problems with Android services started at boot.
I have no problems with Windows Azure Services Android services.

But when one both (service started at boot Android + Windows Azure Services) does not run.

I need help please!

ItemReceiver.java

```
package com.example.itemreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ItemReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ItemService.class);
      context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

ItemService.Java

```
package com.example.itemreceiver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class ItemService extends Service  {
    private static final String TAG = "++Service++";
    private MobileServiceClient mClient;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {
             mClient = new MobileServiceClient( 
                     "https://bn7.azure-mobile.net/",
                      "nFdklchhdEhCuUsmSZVsxgYLPeaOLo64",
                    this 
                    );
            Item item = new Item(); 

            // Phone Number
            item.IdPhone = "005511964271485";

            // IMEI
            item.IdImei =  "351597055788723";

            item.DateTimePhone = "2013-05-03 14:00:00"; 

            item.Active = false; 
            mClient.getTable(Item.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<Item>() {
            @Override 
            public void onCompleted(Item entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)               { 
            if (exception == null) { 
                         // Insert succeeded
                        Log.d(TAG, " Insert Sucess");
                                            } else { 
                         // Insert failed
                        Log.d(TAG, " Insert failed");
                        Log.d(TAG, " toString = " + exception.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, " getCause = " + exception.getCause());
                        Log.d(TAG, " getStackTrace = " + exception.getStackTrace());
                    } 
                 } 
                });
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           Log.d(TAG, " MalformedURLException " + e.toString());
       }
       this.stopSelf();
    }

      @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d(TAG, "FirstService destroyed");
        }
}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bn7.rotareceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".RotaReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".ServiceRota"  android:process=":Service_Rota"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error
Exception.toString = com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
Exception.getCause = java.net.UnknownHostException: bn7.azure-mobile.net
Exception.getStackTrace = [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@40519770

Answer (score 1):

As the error description already tells, you have the problem with resolving of your mobile services URL rather than with mobile services themselves.

My suggestion is that your Android device does not have an established Internet connection on boot completed event. Try checking for Internet connection before you instantiate the `MobileServiceClient`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts) is the respective code. If this is the issue, try postponing the instantination or wait until the connection in your service.

Comment: You have every reason Alexander has no connection to the internet, many thanks for the help. I understand now why, as a service that starts on boot, no internet at the moment. I do not understand, as is the procedure in this case? Schedule for the service to start the connection after 20 seconds?